# Attach hyperlink to a text value

Tags: 2010, jquery

I am trying to update a field in a list to a text value using SPServices() UpdateListItems operation. Now, I need to attach an hyperlink to the text value while updating it in the field. How can we achieve this using jquery. Thanks in advance.